# Silverlight OpenRIA - duplicated requests

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, iis, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight 5, .NET 4.5.1 and OpenRIA.

A silverlight client calls a long-run OpenRIA operation. The operation is asynchronous. From the client side I can see that the function from a code is being called just once. From the IIS server-side on the other hand, the WCF function is called multiple times.

What I have logged through Fiddler - the operation was finished with an error. It was invoked once, but with a message **„NOTE: This request was retried after a Receive operation failed.”**

Request:

```
    GET http://localhost:11213/ClientBin/KEEP-Web-Services-PayrollListService.svc/binary/GetPayrollList?payrollListId=efb1df5d-993a-4c4b-9fe6-013561547632 HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Referer: http://localhost:11213/ClientBin/KEEP.xap
    Accept-Language: pl
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    Host: localhost:11213
    DNT: 1
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Cookie: .KEEP_ASPXAUTH_iPersonel=8673CF25C5650AE86CE77A22B9C9A9D20E7588A077E5EADFFE8F5090F08B48639C9F309B1720BC4AD0D4DE342F149D52234DD8C5F15C0B0CCAD5A074C91E8F14B74FC27D7740A91614DECE034A9F99186375ACEB887E610B32CEA5786BF5EA02D35F144BC49D1E4C254478385EEB4D7E8811959E5494D9D6E9F17D698FCBDC93
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2015 13:06:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 14:06:41.238

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

The situation occurs in IISExpres and IIS 7.5, locally and remotely.

UPDATE 1.

I have found the reason that causes an operation repeated.

> Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The
>   amount of available memory may be low.

What I can do to handle it with OpenRIA (former wcf-ria-services)? I see no custom binding to have any effect to OpenRIA.

Comment: Can you post the full request as it appears in the raw section in Fiddler ? I'm speculating about some http header like "retry-after"

Comment: @mCasamento - I have edited my post. No header like "retry-after" is present.

Comment: I see. I've seen the 504 error with 0 bytes more than 1M times but it has always been a server side error. Just turning on "all CLR Exception" in the debugger give the clear indication about the error. Have you tried this ?
Just to recap, you've implemented a long polling pattern (comet like) but  the request get a 504 before of the configured timeout of 15s, right ?

Comment: @mCasamento - (unfortunately) no exception is thrown in debugger mode. Requests keep incoming to the server every 15 seconds, until the client will get first response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was IIS in 32-bit. Using 64-bit version solves the problem.

P.S. Visual Studio has an option to use IIS-Express in 64-bit. You can also add to the registry:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

12.0 - Visual Studio 2013